# Export Datetime Format into Excel from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, export, export-to-excel

Exporting data from SQL Server to Excel seems like a reasonably simple request.  I just need to write out a few reports for users on a regular basis, nothing too fancy, the same basic report with a few different parameters.
I am doing this by OPENROWSET:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(
            'MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
            ,'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\test1.xlsx;'
            ,'SELECT * FROM [BCT$]'
            )
```

---

I am successful to export all data into excel file from stored procedure of sql server. but problem is format of data like,
DateTime & Number format.

When I export database datetime value into excel than it stored in **Mar 18 2014  6:29PM** this format but actually it was in database like, **2014-03-18 18:29:00**.

I require this format of datetime  **2014-03-18 18:29:00** into Excel.

I have tried different option like :

- Cast require column into datetime , during preparation of last select list.
- I have set one blank excel file in which I have set datetime format on require column.
- I have also check my default windows regions and time zone which is also correct.

When I export datetime value into excel then it by default convert into text so I can't perform any further operation like ordering into this column.

Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance !.

Answer (score 2):

did u try this

convert(nvarchar(19),urdatetimeColumn,121)

in your select query before exporting ??

Comment: I have just check nvarchar conversion and got require format of datetime. but still it stored in text format

Comment: i think you can either order by before exporting in the select query 
or select date column in the exported excel sheet then right click format cells then choose date type and select your desired format

Comment: Yes, you are right but this kind of report is for company CEO. I have to give final report with all modification.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a template row in the first row of the excel file you are exporting to then the rows inserted via OpenRowSet will take on the format of the template row. Otherwise it will just assume a text format for all fields.